Using XProc with saxonJS
The documentation (https://www.xml-project.com/manual/ch02.html) for the XProc processor MorganaXProc-III states that Saxon can be used as an XSLT processor by selecting the appropriate XSLTConnector. However, it seems that only the Java version of Saxon can be used in this way. What about saxonJS, which is freely available on npm? Or does the MorganaXProc-III processor already come with Saxon (which edition)?

Saxon HE 12 (or earlier) Java is also freely available (on Maven and Github) and I think is the proper choice for Morgana as that is a Java application and not a JavaScript/Node.js application.

As for whether Morgana comes with Saxon, the connectors support, in terms of connectors, yes, in terms of the Saxon library/jar, no: 'Please mind that you have to put the requested XSLT processor on the Java classpath too. The easiest way is to just drop the JAR-file into folder “MorganaXProc-IIIse_lib” or “MorganaXProc-IIIee_lib” respectively.'
